# Windows Docker Container Sizing and Scale planning

Tags: windows, docker

I'm currently running Windows 10 with the new containers, and am looking for help on container cpu and memory usage, both for a relatively lightweight workload and if someone has installed the SQL Server 2014 or 2016 images, what their memory footprint is?   I'm just trying to get a better handle on memory requirements, so I can do a better job of planning server sizing.   I'm just interested in the memory working set as reported by Task Manager in Details view.

Comment: Are you asking about only SQL Server images or images in general?

Comment: I'm interested in both, as we're planning a mix of .NET and SQL Server containers.

Comment: This is a really general question, but you might have more luck on ServerFault, I voted to migrate the question.